# why does delete take longer than insert

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Why executing delete statement takes much longer than insert?

As far as I know, delete triggers index and redo change as well as data block. So does delete.

Thus I thought two statements would have similar execution time on the same table. But totally different. What makes this difference?

For reference the dbms vendor is Oracle.  The table has no triggers and two indexes are binded.

It's just a simple delete Delete, `where cdate>201411`.

Comment: Do drop or truncate takes same time as well ?

Comment: Q: What makes you think "delete" necessarily takes longer than "insert" (or, for that matter, "update")?  Q: Does the table in question happen to have both triggers and indexes?  What happens if you run benchmarks without either?  MOST IMPORTANT: did you happen to do an "explain plan"?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing how your insert and delete statements look like and how the table your operating on is defined, and what other sessions are affecting the database etc. At least post the execution plan for your statements.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table fired on delete event?

Comment: In general, on Oracle delete is much slower than insert. Why? This is what the OP asks.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of reasons why DELETEs can take longer than inserts:

The main one is that DELETE is a query: the database has to locate the records you want to delete. Your statement is

> "Delete, `where cdate>201411`."

If CDATE is indexed that's an index range scan at best.  If it's not indexed then its a full table scan.  But if CDATE has a poor clustering factor an indexed read might not perform as well as a full table scan anyway.  Tuning a DELETE is a lot like tuning a SELECT statement.

Either way that's a lot more reading than inserting the record requires.  Why does the database do this?  Because of the need for undo.  When we rollback the database uses the information in the UNDO tablespace to reverse our statement.  For INSERT the undo action is a deletion, so all it needs is the ROWID of the inserted row.  Whereas reversing a DELETE requires re-insertion of the record, so the whole row must be stored in UNDO.

So the DELETE action has to retrieve the whole row and store it in UNDO.  The longer your record the more of an overhead the UNDO management becomes.  (By contrast, the ROWID is a tiny and fixed overhead when inserting.)

Similarly, (as @lalitKumar points out ) the REDO log volumes can be much larger for deletes.  OraFAQ has some [interesting volumetrics here](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2912).

Foreign keys can affect insert and deletions: inserts have to check for the presence of keys in referenced tables whereas deletes have to check for references in dependent tables.  This compares unique key look-ups against non-unique or even un-indexed columns.

Comment: The redo size matters a lot. There is a high redo size for a delete compared to an insert.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to know why **DELETE** takes longer than **INSERT** in general.

Let's take a practical example with **autotrace statistics** to explain the reason.

INSERT autotrace statistics

```
SQL> SET AUTOTRACE ON
SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=1000;

1000 rows created.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1236776825

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT              |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL      | T    |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|      |       |            |          |
|   3 |    FAST DUAL                  |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(LEVEL<=1000)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
         43  recursive calls
         63  db block gets
         32  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
      19748  redo size
        857  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        864  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          5  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
       1000  rows processed
```

DELETE autotrace statistics

```
SQL> SET AUTOTRACE ON
SQL> DELETE FROM t WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000;

1000 rows deleted.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 325486485

--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT    |      |     1 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  DELETE             | T    |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY     |      |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(ROWNUM<=1000)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          8  recursive calls
       1036  db block gets
         15  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
     253264  redo size
        859  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        835  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          2  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
       1000  rows processed

SQL>
```

> When you DELETE a row the whole row goes to rollback segments and is
>   also written into redo log.
>
> When you do an INSERT the redo size is
>   quite less compared to a DELETE.

Let's do a small test, I will use **DBMS_UTILITY.get_time** to compare the timings. I will do a test first with an  index, another without an index.

**Set Up**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2    (A NUMBER
  3    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

**INSERT and DELETE without index:**

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2    l_start NUMBER;
  3    l_loops NUMBER := 100000;
  4  BEGIN
  5
  6    l_start := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
  7
  8    FOR i IN 1 .. l_loops
  9    LOOP
 10      INSERT INTO t
 11        (a
 12        ) VALUES
 13        (i
 14        );
 15    END LOOP;
 16
 17    COMMIT;
 18
 19    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Time taken for INSERT =' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - l_start) || ' hsecs');
 20
 21    l_start := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
 22
 23    FOR i IN 1 .. l_loops
 24    LOOP
 25      DELETE FROM t WHERE a = i;
 26    END LOOP;
 27
 28    COMMIT;
 29
 30    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Time taken for DELETE =' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - l_start) || ' hsecs');
 31
 32  END;
 33  /
Time taken for INSERT =354 hsecs
Time taken for DELETE =10244 hsecs

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Now, let' first **TRUNCATE** the table to set the **HIGH WATERMARK** back to zero.

```
SQL> TRUNCATE TABLE t;

Table truncated.

SQL>
```

**Create an index:**

```
SQL> CREATE INDEX a_indx ON t(A);

Index created.

SQL>
```

**Gather table stats:**

```
SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('LALIT', 't');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**INSERT and DELETE with index:**

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    l_start NUMBER;
  3    l_loops NUMBER := 100000;
  4  BEGIN
  5
  6    l_start := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
  7
  8    FOR i IN 1 .. l_loops
  9    LOOP
 10      INSERT INTO t
 11        (a
 12        ) VALUES
 13        (i
 14        );
 15    END LOOP;
 16
 17    COMMIT;
 18
 19    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Time taken for INSERT =' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - l_start) || ' hsecs');
 20
 21    l_start := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
 22
 23    FOR i IN 1 .. l_loops
 24    LOOP
 25      DELETE FROM t WHERE a = i;
 26    END LOOP;
 27
 28    COMMIT;
 29
 30    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Time taken for DELETE =' || (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - l_start) || ' hsecs');
 31
 32  END;
 33  /
Time taken for INSERT =1112 hsecs
Time taken for DELETE =1474 hsecs

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So, in either case, **DELETE** operation takes longer than **INSERT**.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is similar the topic has been discussed [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/9270272#9270272). I think that the answer is still actual.

> As a rule of thumb I would say a update is usually faster then an
>   delete.
>
> As it had been stated an update has to do less work then a delete. But
>   it depends largely how the update is done and how the table structure
>   for the delete is.
>
> Here are some steps that the database will do when executing each
>   command. These steps are not complete but they help to make the
>   picture.
>
> Update
>
> - lock the record/block
> - execute the before update statement trigger
> - for each row execute the before update row trigger
> - check if there is a (unique/check) constraint of the column
> - change the data
> - if the new value doesn't fit into the current block anymore add a new block for the table (row chaining). This happens often when you
> - update a column value from 5 characters to 1000 characters
> - change/update all indexes on this column
> - for each row execute the after update row trigger
> - execute the after update statement trigger
>
>   Delete
> - lock the record/block
> - execute the before delete statement trigger
> - for each row execute the before update row trigger
> - check if there are FKs pointing to this table
> - if yes do a select on all the detail tables to see if there are child records
> - depending on the FK delete the childs or generate an error message
> - mark the row as deleted. The space is freed for future inserts depending on pctfree and similiar storage parameters
> - change ALL indexes on this table
> - for each row execute the after delete row trigger
> - execute the after delete statement trigger
>
> This is not even including undo information
>
> In general I would think that most actions done for a delete are more
>   expensive than for a update. Especially for an update on an unindexed
>   column where only 1 character is added/changed.
>
> However very often the update/delete is not the limiting factor, but
>   the select that happens before the update and that finds all the rows
>   that need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to delete all of the rows anyway consider using TRUNCATE instead if possible.

If the delete uses a WHERE clause consider you're doing an indexed lookup for efficiency (but remember that updating the index for the delete will cause some overhead too)

There migh be session which are currently using the Current Object (rows might be locked with respect to the your delete records). It's waiting to until the session is cleared or closed.

Rollback segments can also cost you time.

Also for optimising massive deletes please refer :

1.[Link 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/710/best-way-to-delete-very-large-recordset-in-oracle)

2.[Link 2](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/10MinuteSolution/22191)

Comment: I know I should have executed truncate instead of delete. But I am asking because I am in a situation where I have to use delete..

Comment: is reference / rollback / sessions for that field exist?

Comment: why would rollback info slowing down the delete? There is rollback info also for insert.

Comment: Its not rollback info,rollback segments like triggering another table updates can also cause delay,correct me if im wrong.cos there are rollback operation kept at some cases

Comment: Yeah ineffienct information is present. I will post new one with specific clues. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @Hellfire7707 - please *edit this question* rather than posting a new one